# Use MongoDB for caching? JSON or long string as primary key

Tags: json, string, mongodb, caching, primary-key

Can I use MongoDB to build a lookup JSON => JSON?

I think about building a (permanent) cache for some calculations performed by a WebAPI method. Request and Response are object structures (transferred by converting into/from JSON).

As MongoDB is a documentDB the value part seems to be a good fit. I care about the key part.

Requests may have JSON representations of maybe 500 bytes, values maybe 1000 bytes.

There can be millions of cache entries.

Thinking in C# I would look for something like a disk based Dictionary. I tend to a more complex solution like MongoDB because of distribution (cluster) and debugging options (analyse content easier).

I'm sure there are faster or more specialized solutions just for disk based dictionary with json key, suggestions welcome.

But I'm interested in MongoDB suitability (e.g. show stoppers).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB could do this. You can create indexes on fields which contain sub-documents. A query will then return the document when the object you search for exactly matches that sub-document.

However, keep in mind that what MongoDB stores is not [JSON](http://json.org/) but [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) ("Binary JSON"). Even though these are semantically so similar that many drivers and the default shell convert it to and from JSON transparently, there are some subtle differences regarding the data-types which are available.

For example, while JSON has a generic "number" type with an unlimited number of base-10 digits in front and after the decimal point,  BSON has 32bit and 64bit integer types and a 64bit floating point type. Larger values can be stored as a binary string, which is a type without a counterpart in JSON.

When you are looking for a "true" JSON document database, [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB) might be an option.

Comment: I would like to note that OuchDB (sorry, had some severe problems with it) tends to need quite some administration skill and manpower. In my experience, MongoDB is much easier to scale and replicate.

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks for clearing up JSON / BSON -- my use case allows converting in both directions. I will test your index solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/)? Its storing JSON docs natively and [outperforms MongoDB](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20140911005192/en/Couchbase-Dominates-Cassandra-DataStax-MongoDB-Newly-Released#.VRWrPNfD99A). It also has C# support: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/

You can generate digest signatures for your incoming JSON to create keys in the Couchbase and then get related JSON document.